# Windows 8 tile tags are being ignored

Tags: html, windows-8, microsoft-metro, xampp

I'm trying to make a `Windows 8` tile for my website using the following code:

```
<meta name="application-name" content="Home | <?php echo bloginfo('name'); ?>" />
<meta name="msapplication-starturl" content="<?php echo bloginfo('url'); ?>" />
<meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#349ed5" />
<meta name="msapplication-tooltip" content="Tooltip Test" />
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#349ed5" />
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/logo_w144px.png" />
```

The `application-name`, `msapplication-starturl` and `msapplication-navbutton-color` properties work fine and update with just a refresh of the page - no re-pinning necessary - but the `msapplication-tootlip`, `msapplication-TileColor` and `msapplication-TileImage` are being completely ignored.

Notes:

- This is a WordPress site
- IE is also ignoring the favicon for this site
- restarting the machine did not pull in the image
- I am running this site from a XAMPP server on a different computer, accessing it via IP and port numbers
- For another local site, the favicon is picked up but the same three `msapplication` meta tags are ignored and the favicon is used as the tile image

Does anyone have an idea what's going wrong and how I fix it?

[edit]

I have tried putting the image and settings through Microsoft's [buildmypinnedsite.com](http://www.buildmypinnedsite.com/) code generator and using the image and code it spat out, but that made no difference.

Answer (score 2):

The website needs to be accessable with an public Adress - is it an IP or an Domain, it can't be a local IP Adress as localhost or 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

This may be the issue: content="/logo_w144px.png" .

It most likely cannot find the image. Try changing the path or adding fallbacks to jpg.

- content="logo_w144px.png"
- content="../logo_w144px.png"
- content="../img/logo_w144px.png"

...

Comment: That didn't work. I even tried putting the image and settings through Microsoft's [buildmypinnedsite.com](http://www.buildmypinnedsite.com/) code generator, but that made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your `msapplication-TileImage` is `144x144 px .png image` ?

You can see that (Source "Community Additions" part) it is a must, also I had the same problem, when I changed my .png size `72x72 px` to `144x144 px` problem was solved.

Source ; [Customizing the Site Icon (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg491740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely a 144x144 PNG image.

Answer (score 0):

I have just ran into this issue with a similar setup. It ended up being caused by using appendChild (or `.wrap()` in jQuery) on an `<iframe>`. In my case it was because I use FitVids.js.

[Reported the bug here](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/780880/using-appendchild-on-iframe-breaks-windows-8-tile-tags)

The tile tags work properly on any page without an `<iframe>` being modified with appendChild in JS.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to so this today and have found that the image will not display if your site is running under HTTPS.

HTTP works fine...

I can't believe I'm the only person to discover this but have yet to find any info on the web about it.

--  Edit  --

HTTPS does work, but only if you have a fully trusted certificate - not a self-generated one!

Comment: Well I've not even tried it over HTTPS - only HTTP both from a local XAMPP server and a test file on our production server. Thanks for the info, though, I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score -1):

I've done a little experimentation with this stuff, albeit with the Customer Preview release, and have found it to be very unreliable.  A couple of key points:

- If you have a favicon at all, [that will always be chosen as the image](http://ericnelson.wordpress.com/2012/06/10/pinning-sites-in-windows-8-add-two-meta-tags-to-make-it-high-quality/#comment-790)
- Whatever cache is being used for the tiles is separate from the browser cache, and it doesn't seem to be possible to force a refresh, so it's very hit or miss whether or not you see any updates you might make in configuration

Comment: I've not changed the tooltip or ImageColor values at all since the start - they've never been recognised no matter how many times I re-pin or reboot. The tile cache must be unreasonably persistent.
Thanks for the info though, I'll see what I can do about getting my hands on a second Windows 8 machine for more testing.

Comment: @Ultrabenosaurus I got the title to update by physically powering down the machine.  Remember on Win8 a 'reboot' is actually [a suspend/restore by default](http://www.askvg.com/fix-windows-8-restart-and-shutdown-problems-by-disabling-hybrid-shutdown-feature/).

Comment: The title has always worked for me, and updates by just opening/refreshing the webpage.

Comment: @Ultrabenosaurus Initially for me, when I was getting the favicon in the tile, I was getting the page title rather than the one I specified in the `meta` tag

Answer (score -1):

How do you ensure the tile image will be used in place of the favicon?

```
    <title>{$pageTitle}</title>

{* Favicon and Apple touch icon *}
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{$THEME_URL}/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="{$THEME_URL}/apple-touch-icon.png" />

{* Windows 8 tile *}
<meta name="application-name" content="{$siteTitle}"/> 
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#3380aa"/> 
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="{$THEME_URL}/tile.png"/>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide a good answer. See [answer] for more information.